# "A statement is expected here" error ocured in Crystal Report 2008 in formula workshop

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I wrote a formula in the Crystal Reports 2008 Formula Workshop.

I have tried many combination but still facing error

> A statement is expected here

My code is below :

```
If not isnull({Auditproduct.newParam6_Low1}) then
If {Auditproduct.oldParam6_Low1}<>{Auditproduct.newParam6_Low1} then
"-T1: " + totext({Auditproduct.newParam6_Low1}) + " "  & 
//facing formula near"-T1: "ON ABOVE LINE.
If not isnull({Auditproduct.newParam6_Upp1}) then
If {Auditproduct.oldParam6_Upp1}<>{Auditproduct.newParam6_Upp1} then
"-T1 :" + totext({Auditproduct.newParam6_Upp1}) + chr(10)
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution In crystal Report on formula workshop 
on tool tip there is drop down were "Basic Syntax" selected so I changed it to "Crystal Syntax".